# How to improve this Javascript switching of divs?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, switch-statement, boolean

I'm looking for a way to improve that piece of code, as I refuse to believe there is no better way of doing it.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div id = "panel1" onclick = "Function1()">
  First panel
</div>
<div id = "panel2" onclick = "Function2()">
  Second panel
</div>
<div id = "panel3" onclick = "Function3()">
  Third panel
</div>
```

Here is the Javascipt:

```
function Function1() {
  document.getElementById('panel1').style.display = "flex";
  document.getElementById('panel2').style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById('panel3').style.display = "none";
}
function Function1() {
  document.getElementById('panel1').style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById('panel2').style.display = "flex";
  document.getElementById('panel3').style.display = "none";
}
function Function1() {
  document.getElementById('panel1').style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById('panel2').style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById('panel3').style.display = "flex";
}
```

It is supposed to change the display style of blocks.

Comment: *"Better"* how? Does it work?

Comment: Duplicate function names don't make any sense.

Answer (score 0):

JQuery **fadeIn** and **fadeOut** could be an options, smoother transitions. Documentation http://api.jquery.com/fadein/

```
$( "#panel1" ).fadeIn( "slow", function() {
    // Animation complete
  });

$( "#panel1" ).fadeOut( "slow", function() {
    // Animation complete
  });
```

```js
function Function1() {
   $( "#panel1" ).fadeOut( "slow", function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id = "panel1" onclick = "Function1()">
  First panel
</div>
<div id = "panel2" onclick = "Function1()">
  Second panel
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've added toggle functionality to this as I've assumed you would want it.

```js
toggle = () => {
  let allPanels = document.querySelectorAll("div[id^='panel']");
  if (event.target.style.display === 'flex') { // Show all 
    allPanels.forEach(e => {
      e.style.display = "block";
    });
  } else { // Hide some
    let curId = event.target.id;
    allPanels.forEach(e => {
      if (e.id === curId) {
        e.style.display = "flex";
      } else {
        e.style.display = "none";
      }
    });
  }
};
```

```html
<div id="panel1" onclick="toggle()">
  First panel
</div>
<div id="panel2" onclick="toggle()">
  Second panel
</div>
<div id="panel3" onclick="toggle()">
  Third panel
</div>
```

If you do not want it to be toggle-able:

```js
toggle = () => {
  let allPanels = document.querySelectorAll("div[id^='panel']");
  let curId = event.target.id;
  allPanels.forEach(e => {
    if (e.id === curId) {
      e.style.display = "flex";
    } else {
      e.style.display = "none";
    }
  });

};
```

```html
<div id="panel1" onclick="toggle()">
  First panel
</div>
<div id="panel2" onclick="toggle()">
  Second panel
</div>
<div id="panel3" onclick="toggle()">
  Third panel
</div>
```

Hope this helps,